# Excel function not showing result after loaded through power query

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-tables

My power query loads a CSV file in my Excel workbook as table.
The CSV file has values like the following:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.example.com/";"This is an URL.")
```

The issue with that is, that those values are shown exactly this way in the cells of the Excel table. I would like them to calculate the function.

Displayed in cells: =HYPERLINK("https://www.example.com/";"This is an URL.")
What I'd like: [This is an URL.](https://www.example.com/)

When I click into the function of the cell and hit enter, then the hyperlink is displayed correctly.

My question would be, instead of going through each cell to let the function be calculated, is there a way to load it correctly through power query?

Edit: I solved it now by refreshing the cells one by one through a macro:

```
Sub ActivateFormulas()
On Error GoTo skip
Dim c As Variant
Dim s As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each c In Worksheets("main").Range("Table_adnovum_methodology_data").Cells
        c.Select
        s = c.Value
        If Len(s) < 255 Then ActiveCell.FormulaLocal = s
skip:
    Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It's not "nice", but it works. I run it after refreshing the table.

Comment: see https://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/09/12/powerquery-return-clickable-hyperlinks-to-excel/

Comment: The solution in the BI Accountant article still requires "manual" intervention by performing a search and replace after the query refreshes. Changing the CSV per that article would add a step to the PQ and still need a VBA event to process once the query refreshes. Using the .Formula2 property of the range, instead, would at least save the PQ manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way for PowerQuery to directly "convert" your formulas; however, your VBA can hit the entire range all at once rather than looping:

```
    Dim vVal
    vVal = Worksheets("main").Range("Table_adnovum_methodology_data").ListObject.DataBodyRange.Formula2
    Worksheets("main").Range("Table_adnovum_methodology_data").ListObject.DataBodyRange.Formula2 = vVal
```

Edit: I added `.ListObject.DataBodyRange` since operating on the entire range destroys the link between the table and the query. Operating on the DataBodyRange preserves the link.